# How to return amount of a certain letters from a text file using a method

Tags: java, methods, text-files

Assuming I have a text file filled with random words or letters, I need to be able to increment the amount of times a letter is seen. For this example, I am trying to find the letter 'a'. While the program does compile and return a number, the number can either be too high or low concerning the amount of the certain letter I'm looking for. Changing my code around, how can I fix this?

Oh! I should mention that the person I'm sending this code in for wants it to be structured in the form of having a method whereas Problem9 only has the parameters (File, file) and must be constructed into the form of a method

```
package module4labs;
import java.io.File;
import java.io.FileNotFoundException;
import java.util.Scanner;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.InputMismatchException;

public class Module4Labs {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        new Module4Labs();
    }
    
    public Module4Labs() {
        double problemSolution = Problem9(new File("Problem9.txt"));
                System.out.println(problemSolution);        
    }

//Problem 9: Find 'a'
public int Problem9(File file) {
    int counter =0;
    try {
    Scanner input = new Scanner(file);
    ArrayList<String> list = new ArrayList<String>();
    while(input.hasNext()) {
        list.add(input.next());
    }
    
    for (int x=0; x<list.size()-1;x++) {
        if (list.subList(x,x+1).equals('a'));
        counter++;
    }
    input.close();
 } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
    System.out.println(file + "File Not Found.");
    }
 return counter;

}
```

Currently, I'm getting a warning from Eclipse saying "Unlikely argument type for equals(): char seems to be unrelated to List"

Unsure on how to continue with this

Comment: Your code is currently counting the number of lines in the file in an inefficient way. I would start by formatting your code with an automated formatter - Eclipse can do this easily. That will likely highlight one problem with your if-statement, but it will also make the code readable for your audience on StackOverflow.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

*the person I'm sending this code in for wants it to look similar to this* No they don't. This code violates several coding conventions in Java; `Problem9` is a terrible and undescriptive method name. You are counting the appearance of a `char`. Don't hardcode that `char` - pass it to the method and give the method a proper name, like `countChar`. Iterate the lines of your file and then iterate the contents of the line looking for the `char`. Next, don't calculate the result and print it **in** the constructor. I would make `countChar` static, but assuming you must instantiate your class I would do so in `main` and then invoke the method. Like,

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    Module4Labs m4l = new Module4Labs();
    double problemSolution = m4l.countChar(new File("Problem9.txt"), 'a');
    System.out.println(problemSolution);
}

public int countChar(File file, char ch) {
    int counter = 0;
    // This is a try-with-Resources, don't hard code input.close();
    try (Scanner input = new Scanner(file)) {
        while (input.hasNextLine()) {
            String line = input.nextLine();
            for (int i = 0; i < line.length(); i++) {
                if (line.charAt(i) == ch) {
                    counter++;
                }
            }
        }
    } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
        System.out.println(file + " File Not Found.");
    }
    return counter;
}
```

Comment: I'll reword the desc., but the person wanted it *structured* in the form of having a method whereas countChar only has the parameters (File, file) and must be constructed into the form of a method. Thank you for the help, though

Answer (score 0):

We can also use the `java.nio.file` package to accomplish this task. For example,

```
import java.io.File;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.nio.file.Files;

public class CharacterFrequency {
    private String str;

    public CharacterFrequency(File file) {
        try {
            this.str = Files.readString(file.toPath());
        } catch (IOException e) {
            System.err.println(e);
        }
    }

    public int getFrequency(char a) {
        int frequency = 0;
        for (char b : str.toCharArray()) {
            if (a == b) {
                frequency++;
            }
        }
        return frequency;
    }

    public void showFrequency(char a) {
        int frequency = getFrequency(a);
        System.out.printf("The character %c appears %d times\n", a, frequency);
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        if (args.length < 1) {
            System.out.println("Usage: java CharacterFrequency.java path/to/file");
            return;
        }
        File f = new File(args[0]);
        CharacterFrequency cf = new CharacterFrequency(f);
        cf.showFrequency('a');
        cf.showFrequency('z');
        cf.showFrequency('g');
        cf.showFrequency('p');
    }
}
```

I created a file example.txt that has these contents:

```
The soccer player scored a goal.
```

I saved the file example.txt to the same directory as CharacterFrequency.java.

Then I ran the command:

```
% java CharacterFrequency.java example.txt
The character a appears 3 times
The character z appears 0 times
The character g appears 1 times
The character p appears 1 times
```

Answer (score 0):

Other code samples use linewise reading and/or create strings. This is unnecessary - just read `char`s:

```
import java.io.Reader;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.nio.file.Files;
import java.nio.file.Path;

public class CharacterFrequency {

    public static int getFrequency(Path inputPath, char c) throws IOException {
        int frequency = 0;
        int buf = -1;
        try (Reader in = Files.newBufferedReader(inputPath)) {
            while ((buf = in.read()) > -1) {
                if (buf == c) {
                    frequency++;
                }
            }
        }
        return frequency;
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        try {
            if (args.length < 2) {
                System.err.println("Usage: java CharacterFrequency <path/to/file> <character to find>");
                System.exit(1);
            }
            Path inputPath = Path.of(args[0]);
            char c = args[1].charAt(0);
            System.out.printf("Frequency of character %c in file %s is %d%n", c, inputPath.toString(),
                    CharacterFrequency.getFrequency(inputPath, c));
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
}
```